Unknown Memory Hog in Windows 11
I have an HP Omen gaming laptop that recently struggles with memory use hitting close to 100% when playing. Tried restarting to get a fresh picture, checked TaskManager and RamMap and there's lots of memory unaccounted for, is there anything I can do to find out what's hogging the memory and take care of it?
I know Windows does a lot of magic behind the scenes that takes up a good chunk, but I wouldn't imagine it's THIS much.
Screenshots of what I'm seeing:




how are you determining that you are close to 100% RAM use if its not tools like Task Manager that are telling you that?

"memory use hitting close to 100% when playing." Playing what? That would be the culprit.

So taskmanager is showing 66%, which is a far cry from 100%. RamMap is telling us you have 8GB of RAM. Windows 11 + background services (like from nvidia, razer, intel) will easely eat up those 66% of 8GB after a fresh boot. Plenty of it will be mapped out if something needs memory. It all looks normal to me.

it seems weird that you have a windows 11 compatible gaming branded laptop with only 8GB ram. these days 16GB is kinda a minimum (albeit not an official requirement). If you do only have 8GB, then perhaps the best bet is looking into adding more memory. Just browsing with Chrome is more than enough to swamp an 8GB system.
